# HighCharts - Make the pie chart 100% of the div

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I make a `pie` chart fill `100%` of the `div`it is contained in? The `div` has a width of `198px` and it's height is `152px`.

Additionally I would like to have a `linear-gradient` effect inside each pie slice, can you advise on how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you generate sample fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The gradient might be a slight pain because you'll probably want to use the radiant gradient. You should override the background property with the radiant gradient (ensureing the background-color is transparent).
And we'll need to see some HTML in order to tell you how you could adjust it, because just a picture from a highchart is pretty lousy :P Unless we would go to highcharts.org - not ;)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can achieve the full height of the pie chart by setting the `size` attribute in the `plotOptions` of pie and removing `margins`, `spacing` and `titles` from the chart.

**Code**

```
    chart: {           
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size:'100%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
```

**Example** *(updated the fiddle to point to version 2.2.4)*

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/xeb3n/) demonstrating this.

<strike>As to the linear gradients, I don't know if they have been implemented yet, but here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/LCdVd/) showing radial gradients.</strike>

Radial gradients are also part of Highcharts 3.0 now, here is an [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient)

**Update**

<strike>Looks like as of Highcharts 3.0, this is not possible anymore due to the chart auto-scaling within the plot area, an excerpt from their documentation:</strike>

> size: The diameter of the pie relative to the plot area. Can be a percentage or pixel value. Pixel values are given as integers. **The default behaviour (as of 3.0) is to scale to the plot area and give room for data labels within the plot area.** As a consequence, the size of the pie may vary when points are updated and data labels more around. In that case it is best to set a fixed value, for example "75%". Defaults to .

in my opinion this should not be the case since `dataLabels` are disabled. should probably be logged as a [bug](http://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3291)

**Update (Aug 2014)**

As per [Torstein's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069158/torstein-h%C3%B8nsi) comment, this is indeed still possible. [`slicedOffset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.slicedOffset) needs to be set to `0` in addition to the margins begin set. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xV8PM/2/))

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: null,
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            margin: 0
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                slicedOffset: 0,
                size: '100%',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   44.2],
                ['IE7',       26.6],
                ['IE6',       20],
                ['Chrome',    3.1],
                ['Other',    5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500"></div>
```

Comment: I have logged an issue against highcharts regarding this regression: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3291

Comment: You need to set chart.margin and series.slicingOffset to 0: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xV8PM/2/

Comment: Note: If names of series are updated so they cannot fit the chart, the legend will be resized to fit inside and chart will be resized (shrunk), no matter the size set.

Comment: @epoch, any idea if this is still doable with later highchart versions, i.e. 5+?

Comment: @Marko Yes. still robust solution. works as expected

Answer (score 2):

my solutions; (for legend position margin-top error..)

```
chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie',
                    height:'100%' // added...
                },

plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size:'100%',
             height: '100%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and put it inside codeblocks. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)